# How to set correct geo information on pleiades images with RPC model?

Tags: coordinate-system, gdal, gdalwarp, gdal-translate

Now I have pleiades raster (img.tif) and a RPC model (rpc.XML). In the rpc.XML, there are the following lines which can be used to reset geo information.

```
  <RFM_Validity>
    <Direct_Model_Validity_Domain>
      <FIRST_ROW>1</FIRST_ROW>
      <FIRST_COL>1</FIRST_COL>
      <LAST_ROW>19676</LAST_ROW>
      <LAST_COL>18665</LAST_COL>
    </Direct_Model_Validity_Domain>
    <Inverse_Model_Validity_Domain>
      <FIRST_LON>7.393918390116374</FIRST_LON>
      <FIRST_LAT>46.89414037853461</FIRST_LAT>
      <LAST_LON>7.531577540047203</LAST_LON>
      <LAST_LAT>46.98982504658424</LAST_LAT>
    </Inverse_Model_Validity_Domain>
    <LONG_SCALE>0.06584113709872685</LONG_SCALE>
    <LONG_OFF>7.462641690331035</LONG_OFF>
    <LAT_SCALE>0.04690424904394419</LAT_SCALE>
    <LAT_OFF>46.94198271255942</LAT_OFF>
    <HEIGHT_SCALE>245</HEIGHT_SCALE>
    <HEIGHT_OFF>765</HEIGHT_OFF>
    <SAMP_SCALE>9332</SAMP_SCALE>
    <SAMP_OFF>9333</SAMP_OFF>
    <LINE_SCALE>9837.499999999996</LINE_SCALE>
    <LINE_OFF>9838.499999999996</LINE_OFF>
  </RFM_Validity>
```

And I use the following code to reset geo info of img.tif with the value below.
xmin = 7.393918390116374
ymin = 46.89414037853461
xmax = 7.531577540047203
ymax = 46.98982504658424
first_col = 1
last_col = 18665
first_row = 1
last_row = 19676

```
def set_geo_info(in_path, out_path, xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax,
                 first_row, first_col, last_row, last_col, *args):
  '''
  xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax are the longitude and latitude.
  '''
  print('Set Geo Information ...')
  xres = (xmax - xmin) / (last_col - first_col + 1)
  yres = (ymax - ymin) / (last_row - first_row + 1)

  geotransform = (xmin, xres, 0, ymax, 0, -yres)

  ds = gdal.Open(in_path)
  band = ds.GetRasterBand(1)
  arr = band.ReadAsArray()
  [y, x] = arr.shape

  driver = gdal.GetDriverByName("GTiff")
  outdata = driver.Create(out_path, x, y, 1, gdal.GDT_UInt16)
  outdata.SetGeoTransform(geotransform)
  outdata.GetRasterBand(1).WriteArray(arr)
  outdata.FlushCache()

  outdata = None
  arr = None
  band = None
  ds = None

  print("Done.")
```

The result is **kind of** correct, but not entirely.

[image: Position shifting wrt shapefile (WGS84)]

As you can see, the red line is a shapefile (EPSG21781), while the railway in the result is not entirely **overlap** with shapefile. The distance of shifting is not consistent for this whole image. The displacement is larger near the edge of this image.

My questions:

1. Am I heading the right direction to reset geo information?
2. If 1. is correct, I guess the value which I fed into the gdal is wrong. How do I find the correct value from RPC model (rpc.XML)?
3. If 1. and 2. is wrong, how do I do it in a right way?

Comment: Why downvote? Please criticize so I can improve my asking skill.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can warp the image using the RPCs directly with GDAL, e.g.

```
gdalwarp -r cubic -to RPC_DEM=my_dem.tif -rpc -t_srs epsg:4326  my_DIMAP_file.XML my_dimap_file_warped.tif
```

In order to get a good result it is advisable to use a high resolution DEM.
You can do the same programmatically if you prefer by using `gdal.Warp()`

Comment: Thank you. It works, although there's still small displacement, but it's better than before. I use python elevation packge to download DEM. I think it's the reason why there is still small displacement in the output.

Comment: I don't know the details of the product that you have, but it is quite possible that it is a so-called "Ortho-ready" product ( see https://www.orfeo-toolbox.org/CookBook/recipes/optpreproc.html#beware-of-ortho-ready-products ) which means the RPCs were created by projecting to a constant height instead of a DEM. In that case the positional accuracy that can be achieved would indeed be limited.